# Como converter unidades de milhão em unidade de dezenas no R?

Tags: r, matemática, number-format

Suponhamos que tenho o número 80 milhões.

```
Numero = 80000000

print(Numero)

[1] 8e+07
```

Por se tratar de um número grande o R já me mostra em Número Científico, mas eu gostaria de converter esse número que está em Unidade de Milhar, em Unidade de Dezena, ficando algo parecido como:

**80 Mi**

A ideia era exibir um número que fosse mais fácil de visualizar, onde qualquer um que olhe saiba que se trata de 80 milhões. Isso é possível?

Comment: Qualquer coisa [assim](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-custom-scales-with-the-scales-package/)?

Comment: Exatamente! Obrigado pelas referências.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote [`humanize`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/humanize/humanize.pdf):

```
Numero = 80000000000

humanize::count_as_word(Numero)
# [1] "80.0 billion"
```

Comment: Exatamente que eu preciso Willian, no meu exemplo acho que coloquei alguns zeros a mais.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para evitar confusão.